# how to give name header column in option enableRowNumbering igGrid infragistics?

Tags: infragistics

sample from help infragistics

http://help.infragistics.com/jQuery/2011.2/ui.iggridrowselectors

```
//Initialize
$(".selector").igGrid({
    features : [
        {
            name : "RowSelectors",
            enableRowNumbering: true
        },
        {
            name: "Selection"
        }
    ]
});
//Get
var rowNumbering = $(".selector").igGridRowSelectors("option", "enableRowNumbering");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using jQuery to select elements with the class "ui-iggrid-rowselector-header" and then use that to set the text.  For example:

$(".ui-iggrid-rowselector-header")[0].textContent = "RS";

Since this isn't exposed as an option from the RowSelectors feature you may also want to contact [Infragistics support](http://www.infragistics.com/support/default.aspx) and request this feature be added.